# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my project, I have a UITableView with a custom cell, SearchCell. Cell however is returned as a null value, and will crash the app. If I choose to catch the null exception and alloc/init a new cell, it comes up as blank. Here is the following code:

```
    #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return self.workingDatabase.count; This was causing an error for some reason, not too sure
    return 1; //using 1 just for debugging
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InfoCell";
    SearchCell *cell = (SearchCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

    /*
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[SearchCell alloc] init];
    }*/

    // Configure the cell...
    Record *record = [self.workingDatabase objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //set the content
    cell.myName.text = record.ABName;
    cell.myTarget.text = record.ABTarget;
    cell.myVendor.text = record.ABVendor;
    cell.myCatNumber.text = record.ABCatNumber;
    cell.myClonality.text = record.ABClonality;
    cell.myOrganism.text = record.ABSourceOrg;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is your `SearchCell` done all in code or is your custom cell created in IB?

Comment: `SearchCell *cell = (SearchCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];` So you expect this to return a SearchCell? Could you please show the code or explain what you are doing so that that will happen?

Comment: You need to answer rmaddy's question -- the answer to your problem depends on how you created your cell and table view.

Comment: Check these two things. Did you change the class of your prototype cell to SearchCell? Does it have the identifier, "InfoCell"?

Comment: Yep, Identifier and class are right

Comment: Is the capitalization of the identifier correct? It has to match `InfoCell` exactly.

Comment: Yes, just verified this

Comment: If, as you said in a comment, you made this cell in the storyboard, then the code you have above should have returned a valid cell (this is from Apple's docs: "Because the prototype cell is defined in a storyboard, the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method always returns a valid cell. You don’t need to check the return value against nil and create a cell manually"). But you say, that if you log cell it's null?

Comment: I haven't attempted to log the cell but assumed it was null based on my error and the research I've done on the error. By the way I probably should've included the error message from the start: 2013-05-05 23:32:13.860 FinalProject[41167:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471
2013-05-05 23:32:13.860 FinalProject[41167:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: Well, do the log and see what it gives you just to be sure.

Comment: How would I log a Cell?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",cell); right after this line: SearchCell *cell = (SearchCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

Comment: Nifty, I thought you could only do that with NSStrings. It returned Null...well (null) technically

Comment: Is SearchCell a subclass of UITableViewCell? If it is, then I can't see why you're getting null. If you're able to post your project somewhere, or email it to me, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: https://github.com/NLDK/Final-Project

Comment: It didn't upload the .xcodeproj which is one level above it in the directory, I assume you need that too, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your table view is using static cells, not dynamic ones (that's a very important distinction by the way, and should be made clear in any question you post). When you use static cells, you don't need to (and shouldn't usually) implement the UITableView data source methods. You make the outlet connections between the labels and the table view controller itself, instead of to the cell. In fact, you don't need the custom cell class for this at all (that's only needed so you can connect up the outlets of dynamic cells). Then, you can populate the labels just like you would for any other label in a view.

Comment: I think I am using dynamic cells though. Or at least I should be. I have this Array of records and I'm displaying each cell as a record and the entire tableview is the collection of records. Based on searches performed on the database, it will change, becoming larger or smaller.

Comment: Changed it to dynamic from static and now it is working perfectly. I had it set to static so I could have a rough outline UI to show the professor but never changed it back. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: @NLDK, that's not what your table view says in IB. Just change it to dynamic prototypes, and then I think it should work. You'll also need to implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to return the height that you made the cell in IB.

Comment: @rdelmar I'm trying to insert a `UITextField` into the cell from code (because when I do from the IB, it cannot be resized to fit the entire cell). I implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to get the width and the height of the cell but they return 0. I don't want to hardcode values for the `UITextField`'s width and height. Is there any way to get these values dynamically? I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25252140/1077789) with more information as well.